# Addition and Removal of Unique Rows within a Bootstrap Popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm in the midst of creating fairly nuanced popover using Bootstrap and jQuery. I am using jQuery for the addition and removal of rows within the popover. The problem that I am facing involves the institution of functionality with a click event that I have tied to some linked text. I need to be able to reveal a specific hidden row if it is hidden, or propagate a new row if the aforementioned specific row is shown. I have tried two variations on getting this to work with close results.

The first shows the hidden row successfully if hidden, but if shown, the clone within the else statement never occurs:

```
$(document).on("click", ".additional", function (event) {
      if ($('.hiding').parent().parent().hide()) {
           $('.hiding').parent().parent().show();
      } else {
          $('.row:eq(3)').clone(true).insertAfter('.row:last');
      }
});
```

The second allows for the addition of the non-unique rows and hiding of the unique row; however, when the unique hidden row is shown, a cloned non-unique row propagates as well simultaneously. I know why this is, but I've been grappling with flow control (as above) for a fix and I am at a loss.

```
$(document).on("click", ".additional", function (event) {
      if ($('.hiding').parent().parent().hide()) {
          $('.hiding').parent().parent().show();
      }

      if ($('.hiding').parent().parent().show()) {
          $('.row:eq(3)').clone(true).insertAfter('.row:last');
      }     
});
```